# Dumping an SQLite database stored as dll file?

Tags: database, sqlite

A little background first: I need to extract a database from an SQLite dll file for my client who has burned bridges with the previous dev.

I have these 4 files sitting on my desktop:

- System.data.SQLite.Linq.dll
- System.data.SQLite.dll
- SQLite.Interop.dll
- Payroll.exe

I am also given the password for the SQLite DB which Payroll.exe uses to interact with the database. With this is it possible for me to dump an SQL file (so I can work with something familiar)?

Major problem is that I have no experience with C#, .NET stuff and DLL files (I know it stands for Dynamic Link Library!)

I'm willing to dabble and learn some C# to do this.

Comment: First off, none of the files you've listed are the actual database, they're just libraries used to interact with the actual DB.  I'd recommend using a tool like [DotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) or [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) or [JustDecompiler](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) to figure out what your `Payroll.exe` is doing.

Comment: Is there a possibility that the database is "embedded" into `Payroll.exe`? If so does that mean it's impossible to extract?

Comment: They could have embedded an initial snapshot of a database, but any modifications the the data would have been saved to disk, most likely.  You could also use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to monitor for disk activity to see if you can find the DB file.

Comment: Thanks. Used ILSpy, opened up `Payroll.exe`. In one of the files I found `private static string ConnectionStr = "Data Source=.\\System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll; Password=*****"`. Other than that I can't seem to find anything. I will report back any progress.

Comment: Looke like he might have been trying to hide the DB.  Can you open `System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll` in ILSpy?  If not, its probably your database.

Comment: EDIT to previous post: I can see the previous dev's DataTable() calls, it's just finding the origin that's hard. Does DotPeek have an option to list all file sizes? That might give me a better clue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19191/discussion-between-heavyd-and-meiryo).